# How can I get the sub-type that has the smallest yield of a specific type?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I need to know the type of banana that has the smallest yield, what formula should I use? It could be that I need to index the table, then limit the fruit type to banana, then look for the smallest (MIN and MATCH), then index the value of the third column. But I can't find any examples on the internet on how to do that exact thing.

I need a formula that will return the name of the fruit subtype. "Lady Finger Banana" for this case.

[image: excel indexing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MINIFS function can retrieve lowest value meeting (multiple) conditions. Look into that. No need for index match.

Judging by your comment an reading what you need again, INDEX and MATCH is needed after all:
`INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A=[search_value_A])*(B:B=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,[search_value_A])),0))`
This is an array function, so enter it with `ctrl + shift + enter`

It looks for the row number I  column C where both (`*`) your `[search_value_A]` is a match in column A and (`*`)  the lowest value in column B if the `[search_value_A]` matches in column A.

In this case replace `[search_value_A]` with `"banana"`

Comment: I need a formula that will return the name of the fruit subtype. "Lady Finger Banana" for this case.

Comment: `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A="Banana")*(B:B=MINIFS(B:B,A:A;"Banana")),0))` excel won't accept the formula. I'm pressing `ctrl + shift + enter`

Comment: `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A="Banana")*(B:B=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,"Banana")),0))` This works. I replace `;` with `,`. Thanks bro. I really don't have any experience with excel's index array. Where can I learn about index array?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I changed it in my answer. The logic in the array is that it checks for a match to be TRUE (MATCH `1` is TRUE, MATCH `0` equals FALSE). Then you can mention a range and criteria between `(` .. `)` and it calculates the criteria in that range is TRUE/FALSE (1 or 0). If you separate two conditions by `*` it will check the result 1 or 0 for the first condition in the first cell of the given first range against the second condition in the given second range and multiply those. If both are TRUE that will result in (1*1) 1. If one or both are FALSE it will result in 0 (0*0 or 0*1 or 1*0)

Comment: You can add more conditions/ranges by adding extra `*(range=condition)`